# Duplicate symbols in workspace using same static library

Tags: ios, xcode

A is main project. There are Four three subproject- B, C D added in main project A. All of three sub project generate a static library file ie .a

Subproject B require C in order to compile so C is added as a static library inside  B subproject.D  also require C to compile and generate lib file so C is also added inside D subproject as a static library.

Now main project A require B and D  to compile and generate .app file. So both B and D added as a library files  inside A project.

Now issue is while compiling project I am getting duplicate symbols linking error because C is added two times in main project via B and D.

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Operation._requestKey in:
    /Users/sandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/square-fananfxhlvhxxgfqnkzssqckfmmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTeamCBService.a(Operation.o)
    /Users/sandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/square-fananfxhlvhxxgfqnkzssqckfmmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCBService.a(Operation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Operation._sequenceNumber in:
    /Users/sandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/square-fananfxhlvhxxgfqnkzssqckfmmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTeamCBService.a(Operation.o)

Please let me know how can I resolved this problem so that there will be no kinking error. Is there a way to add C inside multi subproject to avoid duplication issue.

Comment: a/ stop using static libraries b/ include every static library only once, all project should include only the headers

Comment: Thanks Sultan can you explain more about it.